# MySQL table PRIMARY KEY question?

Tags: sql, mysql, primary-key

I' was wondering should my primary key look like this `PRIMARY KEY (id, category_id, posts_id)` or look like this `PRIMARY KEY (id)`?

Here is my MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE posts_categories (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
posts_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id, category_id, posts_id),
UNIQUE KEY (category_id, posts_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple column key is called a [**Composite Key**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx) or a [**Compound Key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key)

As stated they are completely valid and have benefits. See links. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using:

```
PRIMARY KEY (category_id, posts_id)
```

The `id` value will always be unique - what won't be, is the paring of `category_id` and `posts_id`.

But I missed that you already have a unique key defined on the `category_id` and `posts_id` columns, so you're primary key could be just the `id`.  But the primary key means that it will be a clustered index - you'll be searching for these two columns more than you would be the `id` column so searches should improve minutely over a non-clustered index on the two columns.

Comment: the `UNIQUE KEY (category_id, posts_id)` is there to stop duplicate entries.

Comment: @OMG Ponies so what are you trying to say?

Comment: @maximus: That's vague - what do you not understand?

Comment: So should my unique and primary keys look like this if I keep the id
`PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY (category_id, posts_id)`

Comment: @maximus: No, my initial advice remains - frankly, I don't see any use in the `id` column.

Comment: @maximus: index the `id` if you like, but IMO it'd be a waste.