# Which column should I make the primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema, rdbms

I'm making a table

Mobile Models Information

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| linktospecs | varchar(255)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(30)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| company     | varchar(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In this table, each mobile from any handset maker will appear only once, and with it, other information like its manufacturer's name and an official link to its specifications. That's all I can think of now.

What I want is, that since the `name` column would be inherently unique (two rows of same mobile models would be stupid), I want to be able to index using it, simply, because in my application, when a user searches for a mobile name, I would use the `name` column to retrieve all other columns from this table.

But in many examples I have seen people use an extra simple ID column that auto increments to keep it as a simple primary key. 
So, my question is, do I need to keep the `ID` column or should the unique `name` column be sufficient to use this table?
I'm new to databases and SQL.

Comment: Well, I would keep the ID column, but that's a long debate. Try to google `surrogate vs primary key`, and find your preferred philosophy...

Comment: what i understand from the tutorials on the Internet about SQL, `unique` means a column that would have unique values, so I should logically just use `name` as the primary key. But I'm new to SQL and databases, so I need an outside opinion before I make my stuff live.

Comment: Using an ID is a good idea. You can then update any of the other fields without breaking links to other tables. Everything can access records by ID.

Comment: Even if you do decide to use an `ID` column, please do *also* apply a `UNIQUE` index on `name`, if you want only unique values in that column. Remember, just because there's a primary key (in whatever form), you ought to also enforce any secondary keys also. This keeps your database cleaner.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did do that when I created the table. Here's the `show create table` dump of this table: http://pastebin.com/3DBYpDSZ
That's what you're saying right?

EDIT - Actually this is how I created it. Different from the dump:
http://pastebin.com/gCTkJmgB

Answer (score 2):

Having an ID column as the primary key is always a good idea because it will never change. If you need to change the name of a phone, and name is the primary key, then any previous references to that phone will immediately stop working because the primary key value is no longer there. On the other hand, if you have a unique ID for each one, you can change the name without affecting the ID, and all previous references will remain valid.

It's also possible that two different companies may come out with phones with the same name, in which case if name were your primary key then you would only be able to store information on one of them.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't realize changing of a phone model's name, it's not a high probability, but it could happen, and I don't want to break my database (if that's something possible)

Answer (score 0):

> The primary key means that it will be a clustered index - you'll be searching for your `name` column more than you would be the `id` column so searches should improve minutely over a non-clustered index. -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543719/2724079

Comment: so you're saying that a composite key of `(name,company)` is a better idea than using `ID`? I'll be having not more than 1000 records for this table.

Comment: I meant `PRIMARY KEY(NAME,COMPANY)`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer ID, because name may match like Nokia 500 and HTC 500. You may not add company name in model name. In thise cases you may get multiple. Its better to use "ID" as key in this scenario.

If you prefer not using ID as a additional column then go with combination of company and name as key.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using `ID` column would be better, as if in near by future if you want to add some functionality which includes foreign Key( primary key of a table that appears in other table) concept then Using `ID` may simply your task and also your effort in various aspect
(If you need to change the name of a phone, and name is the primary key, then any previous references to that phone will immediately stop working because the primary key value is no longer there)